# omniauth-google-oauth2 calendar sync giving invalid credential

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api-client, omniauth-google-oauth2

I am using omniauth-google-oauth2 with branch: 'v0.2.10' for below mentioned scopes in code

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, APP_CONFIG['google_oauth2']['client_id'], APP_CONFIG['google_oauth2']['client_secret'], {
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  redirect_uri: "#{APP_CONFIG['site_url']}auth/google_oauth2/callback",
  skip_jwt: true,
  prompt: 'consent',
  provider_ignores_state: true
}
end
```

But when i try to sync calendar, it gives me invalid_credential error as below

```
auth/failure?message=invalid_credential?...
```

No more details available in response.

Please suggest me if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `APP_CONFIG['site_url']` come with slash in the end or not?
anyway i thank it most be like that:
`#{APP_CONFIG['site_url']}/auth/google_oauth2/callback`
instead of : `#{APP_CONFIG['site_url']}auth/google_oauth2/callback`

Comment: Yes it is coming with slash itself so I don’t see any issue with that

Comment: can you try this guide ? https://dev.to/gautamsawhney/integrating-with-google-calendar-in-a-rails-app-the-right-way-alo

Comment: Above steps will come after generating access token, i am facing issue in generating access token